# How to shoot bullets when space bar is pressed using LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I did it as follows:

```
...
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)) {
   shoot();
}
...
```

The problem is that if I keep pressing SPACE many bullets are created. What I want is that the bullet is shot only when I press SPACE but not while I'm pressing the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a look at the documentation for the library, and it doesn't seem to expose any other way of getting key presses (particularly key down/release). In such a case you can keep track of keep changes yourself with a `spaceAlreadyPressed` variable that persists between frames.

```
...
boolean spaceIsPressed = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE);
if (spaceIsPressed && !spaceAlreadyPressed) {
   shoot();
}
...
spaceAlreadyPressed = spaceIsPressed;
```

It may be safer to use a `spaceIsPressed` variable in case the input state changes unexpectedly.

---

Alternatively, if you want to make it shorter, you can use logical laws to reduce to the following, where `canShoot` also persists between frames and has an initial value of `false`.

```
...
canShoot = !canShoot && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE);
if (canShoot) {
   shoot();
}
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Libgdx `InputProcessor` interface has methods to receive `keyDown` and `keyUp` events.  This is probably what you should be using.